# Is it really necessary to unplug devices from the wall before connecting HDMI?

Tags: hdmi

I was under the impression that HDMI was built to be hot-swap ready... like a USB device. I was told recently that unplugging HDMI while devices were powered on was risky and could actually cause hardware damage. Sure enough... my PS3 manual states that you must turn off and completely unplug both the TV and PS3 before connecting/disconnecting the HDMI cable. Same instructions in my digital camera's manual. Is this really necessary to completely unplug devices from the mains, or are they just covering their butts? Turning the power off is easy enough, but it would be a huge hassle to unplug my wall mounted TV just to connect my camera for a slideshow...

Any thoughts?

Comment: you already have a clear and definative answer, so why are you asking us?  This is a waste of time.

Comment: Because some people say it's absolutely safe, and some people say it's absolutely dangerous. There is no definitive answer that I can find. Product manuals try to cover all the bases to cover their butts... they don't necessarily tell you how things really are. I think it's a valid question, and your response is unhelpful and "a waste of time".

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment, as I'm not sure about it. But the process of unplugging and plugging in a HDMI cable can generate ESD. If powered up, this could potentially cause latchup in the receiver IC, often leading to device failure (i.e. smoke released.) If there is no power, latchup cannot happen. Instead of latchup it could also be getting into an unexpected state due to erroneous/mixed signals which might cause lots of weird and wonderful problems.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't understand the need to completely remove the devices from the power outlet though. Wouldn't it be enough to just shut them off?

Comment: This is a consumer electronics question. If you were planning on designing an HDMI device and where tying to figure out what was needed to make it hotswappable, that would be acceptable, but not this.

Comment: Sorry. First time using stack exchange.

Comment: If you would like a site to ask consumer electronics at, go support this proposed site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics?referrer=nuAsQkb6FnELmsS17ULV8A2

Comment: @bob, nothing to be sorry about, stack exchange attempts to keep their sites relatively focused on a subject to attempt to keep a specific group of experts. Consumer electronics support is off-topic to our site, but it seems you have already mostly seen an answer. If you have power then latchup can occur, without power there is nothing to have latch on.

Comment: This actually has a electronics-related answer: They may be worried about inductive kickback when making/breaking connections. Especially when you have long cables, like 50-footers snaking across the living room, the inductive spike from plugging or unplugging a cable can be quite significant! And while there are anti-ESD devices on HDMI inputs (and perhaps outputs,) the signal bandwidth is high enough that you can't really put enough capacitance on the interface to properly protect against the inductive spikes.